# pscp: tilde '~' not recognized as home directory, how to fix?

Tags: linux, windows, putty

When I use pscp to copy file between windows and linux, symbol '~' does not seem to work for home directory. Is there a way to fix it?

```
C:\>pscp file user@address:~/
pscp: unable to open ~/: failure
```

Comment: `pscp file user@address:` should be to the home directory.  You don't need the `~/`

Comment: @stark, thank you. I didn't know that.